# Setting timeout while invoking web service asynchronously

Tags: c#, web-services

I am calling an external web service from a windows service using C#.

The web service is in .NET. The Web method GetRandomNumber() returns a random integer. The GetRandomNumber() is invoked asynchronously
The web service client code is as below:

```
Service1 s1 = new Service1();
s1.Timeout = 2000;
s1.GetRandomNumberCompleted += new GetRandomNumberCompletedEventHandler(s1_GetRandomNumberCompleted);
s1.GetRandomNumberAsync();
```

I am setting the timeout to 2secs (2000 ms). The web service call, in most of the cases takes 5-10 secs. But in this case the time out does not occur.
Even after the timeout period is over, the client gets the data.
I am missing some thing OR is there any other way to use time out while invoking the web service Asynchronously?

-N

;

Answer (score 0):

Here's an excerpt from an Article on MSDN that should help.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647786.aspx#scalenetchapt10_topic14

> **Asynchronous calls to a Web service.**
>   In this case, you should decide on the
>   number of seconds you can wait for the
>   Web service call to return the
>   results. When using a WaitHandle, you
>   can pass the number of milliseconds
>   the executing thread is blocked on the
>   WaitHandle before it aborts the
>   request to the Web service. This is
>   shown in the following code snippet.

```
MyWebServ obj = new MyWebServ();
IAsyncResult ar = obj.BeginFunCall(5,5,null,null);

// wait for not more than 2 seconds
ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(2000,false);
if (!ar.IsCompleted) //if the request is not completed  { 
  WebClientAsyncResult wcar = (WebClientAsyncResult)ar;
  wcar.Abort();//abort the call to web service 
}
else
{ //continue processing the results from web service }
```